# Localhost - .net6 api project returning empty payload, although I'm getting a 200 OK response status

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

On a small project developed with React (running locally on localhost:3000), when doing a fetch to my local API(.net6 project), I'm getting a 200 response:

[image: This is the request made]

However the response comes totally blank:
[image: Response comes blank]

If I run the same call from swagger on the API Project I get the response just fine.

My controller currently is using a mediator so it looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("Authenticate")]
[ProducesResponseType(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Post))]
public async Task<TokenResponse> AuthenticateAsync([FromBody] Authenticate.AuthenticateCommand command)
{
    var response = await _mediator.Send(command);
    return response.Resource;
}
```

So maybe there is something there not working?

Because if I replace the controller response like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> AuthenticateAsync([FromBody] Authenticate.AuthenticateCommand command)
{
    return new JsonResult(new { response = "OK" });
}
```

I'm getting it just fine:

[image: If]

Something suspicious that I don't get when shooting with Swagger is this on the Chrome network tool:

[image]

That message "Caution: request is not finished yet!", not sure what it means.

Any help is welcome and appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: If you have a client that works and another that doesn't, the first step is to use Fiddler or another proxy to investigate the differences between the two calls.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary using fiddler I got to see that the response is coming with all the values I need.

Comment: To finish the flow and get the response in chrome I've needed to do
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((value) => value);

in js. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fiddler I got to see that the response was coming with all the values I've needed.

To finish the flow and get the response in Chrome, after the fetch I've needed to do:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((value) => value);
```

In the javascript side of the thing and that finished the flow.

Thanks!!!